# Free Driving Mode - Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am trying to make a passive navigation system 'free driving mode', I've looked everywhere including the docs and have no idea how to move forward with the 'PassiveLocationManager' (https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/free-driving/).

'Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationManager' to expected argument type 'NavigationLocationManager?''

See code below...

```
struct NavView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    private let nav: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<NavView>) -> MGLMapView {
        nav.delegate = context.coordinator
        nav.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        nav.locationManager = PassiveLocationManager(dataSource: PassiveLocationDataSource(directions: Directions.shared, systemLocationManager: CLLocationManager()))
    
    return nav
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<NavView>) {
        //
    }
}
```